# How should i dockerize a NestJS with Prisma server?

Tags: postgresql, docker, nestjs, prisma, supabase

Im really newbie to docker, so I was following [this tutorial](https://www.tomray.dev/nestjs-docker-compose-postgres#add-postgres-to-docker-compose) of how to dockerize it. The image builds fine but when running the container, prisma cannot connect to the database. The database is hosted in `supabase`.

In the `docker-compose.yaml` Im setting the connection string as

```
environment:
  DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@$db.ieikcwdztopjvzzgdppu.supabase.co:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}
```

This is the error Im getting

```
PrismaClientInitializationError: Authentication failed against database server at `db.ieikcwdztopjvzzgdppu.supabase.co`, the provided database credentials for `postgres` are not valid.
```

I even tried to hardcode the connection string without any env reference, but i got the same result.

This is the full `docker-compose.yaml`

```
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      # Only will build development stage from our dockerfile
      target: development
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@$db.ieikcwdztopjvzzgdppu.supabase.co:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}
    postgres:
      image: postgres
      restart: always
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
        POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
        POSTGRES_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
        POSTGRES_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}
      ports:
        - '5432:5432'
      volumes:
        - docker-nest-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app

    # Run a command against the development stage of the image
    command: npm run start:dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Comment: Since you're configured to point at an external database, you don't need the `postgres` container.  Do the `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` (in a `.env` file?) match that database's credentials?  You also should be able to remove the `volumes:` that hide the image's code and the `command:` override.

Comment: @DavidMaze So my file should look like this? https://imgur.com/ZvxZh6m 
It's still happening the same thing. The credentials are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was that the password had the character `$`. So it was getting replaced when generating the image. So i escaped it as `$$`